# Javascript Code Works on Chrome and Crashes Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a JavaScript code on my page that is suppose to load a Java Applet when clicking an image.

It's working fine on Chrome. When I load the same page on Firefox it crashes the browser.

Here are the snippets:

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var appletTag;

    hideApplet(); // replace applet with clickable image
    var pic2 = new Image(703,421); // preload mouse over image 
    pic2.src = "pic2.png";

    function hideApplet() {
        var appletbox = document.getElementById('appletbox');
        appletTag = appletbox.innerHTML;

        if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
            var params = "";
            var p = appletbox.getElementsByTagName("PARAM");
            for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                params += p[i].outerHTML;
            }
            appletTag = appletTag.replace("</APPLET>", params+"</APPLET>");
        }

        appletbox.innerHTML = '<img src="gray.png" name="pic1"
                                width="703" height="421"
                                style="cursor:pointer;background-color:gray;"
                                onMouseOver="mouseOverImage()"
                                onMouseOut="mouseOutsideImage()"
                                onclick="showApplet()">';
    }

    function showApplet() {
        var appletbox = document.getElementById('appletbox');
        appletbox.innerHTML = appletTag;
    }

    function mouseOverImage() {
        document.images.pic1.src = pic2.src;
    }

    function mouseOutsideImage() {
        document.images.pic1.src = "pic1.png";
    }
</script>
```

And the divbox that calls this:

```
<div id="appletbox" style="width:703px;height:421px;">
    <applet code="TestApplet.class" codebase="."
       width="703" height="421">
    </applet>
```

Could anyone lend me a hand? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be a bit clearer than: crashes the browser? Do you see an error in firebug or so? I am a bit doubtful your javascript can make the firefox exe itself crash.

Comment: As soon as I load the page, Firefox closes and shows up a box "Mozilla Crash Reporter"

Comment: Tried it out on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jPZjc/ and it does indeed crash firefox. If java crashes firefox also crashes, so it might be related to that. Have you taken a look at: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/963444 and https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.mozilla.org%2Fquestions%2F963444&ei=DTb1Uc2DO8bJOYnCgaAD&usg=AFQjCNEcjJ4RP2drEGuFPpdW8dqU3biGGQ&sig2=UGgO6S3D_iUYwU9fDsPTtg?

Comment: Looks like it's more likely to be related to the Java applet, possibly the `codebase="."`. There's nothing in the JS that looks particularly strange, it's all just vanilla JS doing everyday stuff

Comment: I've switched to a different applet code and its still crashing.